# Fluid doesn't work, particles simply won't appear

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm following this tutorial precisely step by step (I'm using blender 2.92) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3mhJXuveFo&t=91s
When it comes to 1:26, the particles just dont show up. What could be the problem and solution?

Obs: I have tried multiple sizes, checked if all values are set right but I can't find the problem's source.

Comment: As it stands, we have very little info to go on to pinpoint your issue.  Could you please include some screenshots of both what you are attempting (so that readers don't have to go elsewhere and watch a youtube video to understand the question) and what it is doing instead?

Comment: ...and providing your blend file would help too